# Comparing sums of two series based on comparing the underlying sequences' terms.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification

If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ are convergent, and $a_n \leq b_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, with $a_n < b_n$ for at least one $n \in \mathbb{N}$, prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n < \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$.

My attempt:

For every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ define $\sigma_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k$ and $\tilde{\sigma}_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} b_k$. If $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ is an index with $a_{n_0} < b_{n_0}$, then we can write for every $m \in \mathbb{N}$ with $m > n_0$:
$$\sigma_m = \sum_{k=1}^{n_0}a_k + \sum_{k=n_0+1}^{m}a_k$$
and $$\tilde{\sigma}_m = \sum_{k=1}^{n_0}b_k + \sum_{k=n_0+1}^{m}b_k$$
therefore
$$\lim_{m\to\infty}(\sigma_m)=\lim_{m\to\infty}(\sum_{k=1}^{n_0}a_k)+\lim_{m\to\infty}(\sum_{k=n_0+1}^{m}a_k)=\sum_{k=1}^{n_0}a_k+\lim_{m\to\infty}(\sum_{k=n_0+1}^{m}a_k)$$
and
$$\lim_{m\to\infty}(\tilde{\sigma}_m)=\lim_{m\to\infty}(\sum_{k=1}^{n_0}b_k)+\lim_{m\to\infty}(\sum_{k=n_0+1}^{m}b_k)=\sum_{k=1}^{n_0}b_k+\lim_{m\to\infty}(\sum_{k=n_0+1}^{m}b_k)$$
Now, since $\sum_{k=1}^{n_0}a_k < \sum_{k=1}^{n_0}b_k$, and for every $m \in \mathbb{N}$ with $m > n_0$: $$\lim_{m\to\infty}(\sum_{k=n_0+1}^{m}a_k) \leq \lim_{m\to\infty}(\sum_{k=n_0+1}^{m}b_k)$$
it follows that $$\lim_{m\to\infty}(\sigma_m) < \lim_{m\to\infty}(\tilde{\sigma}_m)$$
i.e. $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n < \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$$

Comment: The passage to the limit doesn't conserve the strict inequality.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam Could you please specify which step doesn't conserve the strict inequality?

Comment: It is correct but you could take $a_{n_0}$ instead of $\sum_1^n_0 a_k$

Comment: @AbdallahHammam Unfortunately I still don't understand what you mean. Could you be a little more specific?

Comment: You approach is correct but too long.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p\geq 1$ such that $a_p<b_p$,

put $r=b_p-a_p>0$.

then

$$\forall n>p \;\;\sum_{k=1}^n( b_k - a_k)\geq r$$

$$\implies \forall n>p\;\; \sum_{k=1}^n b_k- \sum_{k=0}^n a_k   \geq r$$

$$\implies \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} b_k-\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} a_k\geq r>0.$$